# Is there any way to simplify this list comprehension with if statement method?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to take a string and remove vowels from words with more than 4 characters.

Is there a more efficient way to write this code?

(1) Make an array from string.

(2) Loop through an array and remove vowels from strings with more than 4 characters.

(3) Join strings in array to from new string.

Thanks!

```
def abbreviate_sentence(sent):

    split_string = sent.split()
    for words in split_string:
        abbrev = [words.replace("a", "").replace("e", "").replace("i", "").replace("o", "").replace("u", "")
                        if len(words) > 4 else words for words in split_string]
        sentence = " ".join(abbrev)
        return sentence


print(abbreviate_sentence("follow the yellow brick road"))      # => "fllw the yllw brck road"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the outer `for` because you're already iterating inside. On another note, you can replace multiple `replace`s with another list comprehension that would be nested inside the already existing comprehension.

```
# for words in split_string:   <- This line is not required
vowels = 'aeiou'
abbrev = [''.join([x for x in words if x.lower() not in vowels]) if len(words) > 4 else words for words in split_string]
sentence = " ".join(abbrev)
return sentence
```

Or abstract the forming of string part to a new function probably adding to its readability:

```
def form_word(words):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    return ''.join([x for x in words if x.lower() not in vowels])

def abbreviate_sentence(sent):
    split_string = sent.split()
    abbrev = [form_word(words) if len(words) > 4 else words for words in split_string]
    sentence = " ".join(abbrev)
    return sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

Austin's solution or the one below should both work. I don't think either is much more efficient computationally than what you have now so I'd focus on readability and reasonability.

```py
def abbreviate_sentence(sent):
    abbrev = []
    for word in sent.split():
        if len(word) > 4:
            abbrev.append(words.replace("a", "").replace("e", "").replace("i", "").replace("o", "").replace("u", ""))
        else:
            abbrev.append(word)
    return " ".join(abbrev)


print(abbreviate_sentence("follow the yellow brick road"))
```

Comment: You might be missing a "abbrev = []".